# Match Pandas dataframes on datetime delta days condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

print(df)

```
          perid     completion_date  store_banner
0       15001703     2020-09-16           0
1       1000190      2020-07-21           2
...
```

print(df1)

```
         perid      status    substatus  sample_date
0      15001703       4            3    2020-09-20
1      15024030       5            2    2020-11-05

...
```

I would like to merge those two frames, so that columns from df1 are added to df (left merge), if *perid* codes match and difference in days between *sample_date* and *completion_date* is less or equal than 14 days.

In pseudocode:

- (df.perid == df1.perid) & ( (df1.sample_date - df.completion_date) <= 14 days)

Thus, obtaining (in the case of the example above):

print(final_df)

```
          perid     completion_date  store_banner      status    substatus  sample_date
0       15001703     2020-09-16           0              4           3      2020-09-20
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with filter subtracted columns converted to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df1['completion_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['completion_date'])
df2['sample_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['sample_date'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on='perid')
df = df[(df.sample_date - df.completion_date).dt.days <= 14]

print (df)
      perid completion_date  store_banner  status  substatus sample_date
0  15001703      2020-09-16             0       4          3  2020-09-20
```

Comment: Correct indeed; I'd maybe consider adding both conditions <= 14 & >= 0. For the sake of clarity, completion date refers to a document signature and sample to a test; hence, a negative value would mean that I'd sign after making the test.

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - Then use `(df.sample_date - df.completion_date).dt.days.between(0, 14)` instead `(df.sample_date - df.completion_date).dt.days <= 14`